# Unable to load desktop site using WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am unable to load a website like whatsapp web using WKWebView. The website loads but it doesn't let me use it as it says Safari 10+ Required. When I change it to "Chrome Safari" it still gives me a warning saying that it needs Chrome 60+ to work. How do I solve this issue?

Here's my Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    let defaultURLString = "https://web.whatsapp.com"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let savedURL = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "webViewUrl") {
            // Load webview with url here
            
            let wkWebConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            wkWebConfig.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 RuxitSynthetic/1.0 v9399630793 t38550 ath9b965f92 altpub cvcv=2"
            let webView = WKWebView(
                frame: CGRect.zero,
                configuration: wkWebConfig)
           
            view = webView
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: savedURL))!
        } else {
            // Load default url here
         
            let wkWebConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            wkWebConfig.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17"
            let webView = WKWebView(
                frame: CGRect.zero,
                configuration: wkWebConfig)
            view = webView
            if let defaultURL = URL(string: self.defaultURLString) {
                webView.load(URLRequest(url: defaultURL))
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if let currentUrl = webView.url {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(currentUrl, forKey: "webViewUrl")
        }
    }

}
```

Logs:

```
2021-03-29 20:03:51.919329+0530 Whatsapp Web for iPad[13152:2083381] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Whatsapp Web for iPad
2021-03-29 20:03:51.919378+0530 Whatsapp Web for iPad[13152:2083381] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2021-03-29 20:03:51.919419+0530 Whatsapp Web for iPad[13152:2083381] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2021-03-29 20:03:52.268277+0530 Whatsapp Web for iPad[13152:2083410] Metal API Validation Enabled
```

And yes, I do have "Allow Arbitrary Loads" set to "YES" in my info.plist file.

Thanks in Advance!

[image: The Screen I see]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all applicationNameForUserAgent probably isn't what you want since that gets appended to the end of the default user agent string.  You are probably looking for WKWebView.customUserAgent which will completely override the default user agent.

For setting desktop mode there is a delegate method in WKNavigationDelegate you can use to specify desktop mode. Introduced in iOS 13.  If you don't set the user agent manually with customUserAgent then WKWebView will automatically use a desktop user agent instead of a mobile one.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, preferences: WKWebpagePreferences, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences) -> Void) {
    preferences.preferredContentMode = .desktop
    decisionHandler(.allow, preferences)
}
```